# My bike isn't getting any power at all what should I do?

Tags: motorcycle, power

The bike is a 2013 Hyosung GT250

I've replaced all the fuses and the battery is good. But when I turn the key I don't get any power to anything at all.

Comment: Have you checked the key switch? Is it getting a supply? Is it supplying power?

Comment: Do you have any add-ons or accessories that drain electricity? Chinese made bikes do not have a good reputation for their electric work.